# DXL Release memory after changing from edit mode to read mode?

Tags: memory-management, ibm-doors

I'm stuck in one DXL problem and really appreciate any helps. I have to create links in a lot of modules and therefore have to open them in edit mode. But that will use more than 2GB memory of DOORS, if I open them in edit mode at one time. So I decide to open each of them in edit mode to create links and then downgrade to read only mode. Howewer this way doesn't release memory either.

Is there a way to release memory caused by edit mode?

Thanks for any your helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can save and close the module in the loop after you are done adding the link.

```
Folder f = current
Item i
Module mod

for i in f do
{
  if(type(i) "" == "Formal")
  {
    mod = edit(fullName(i) "", false)

    //process and add links here

    save mod
    close mod
  }
}
```

Closing the module will release the resources, this may not be what you are looking for. If not please explain what you are trying to do in your program.

Answer (score 0):

The best chance to work around your problem may be to open as less modules at once as possible and  to close them if you're finished with them. If this doesn't solve your problem because two of your modules already consume all the memory, you could switch to a 64bit OS and DOORS client (if available) and upgrade to 4, 8 or 16GB of RAM.

BTW: Memory consumption of DOORS is a pain in the ass ;-) I developed quite a lot DXL scripts for an old version (8.3) of DOORS and complex scripts with a lot of strings may aggravate the memory consumption. Therefore I encourage you to search for possible memory leaks in all DXL scripts which are executed directly or indirectly by your script. Most DOORS modules contain DXL attributes or columns which can cause memory allocations which won't be freed if the corresponding module is closed.

Answer (score 0):

So I declare Array with the open modules and at the end close it.

```
int sizeOfOpenModules = 0
Array openModules = create (1,1)
```

when I open new module I do:

```
 put (openModules, m, 1, sizeOfOpenModules)
```

when want to get one of the open modules:

```
Module m = (Module get (openModules, 1, i))
```

And at the end:

```
void closeAllOpenModules () {
    for (i = 0; i < sizeOfOpenModules; i++) {
        Module m = get (openModules, 1, i)
        save (m)
        close (m)
    }
}
```